# matplot fig printing and not displaying the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When I use `display(fig1)` it prints the following:

```
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
```

This is my code that defines fig 1:

```
fig1 = plt.Figure()
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(ress)
ax.set_ylabel('Ressistance (Ohms)')
ax.set_xlabel('Index')
ax.set_title(PlotName)
ax.set_ylim(min(ress)*.9999,max(ress)*1.0001)
display(fig1)
```

When I run `display(fig1)` or just `fig1` in a new cell, it prints the same thing. But when I run:

```
plt.plot(ress)
display(fig1)
```

it actually displays `fig1` (and the `plt.plot`), BUT the axes and title are on the `plt.plot(ress)` and not my `fig1`. I am obviously doing something wrong, since this is reproducible, but I can't see what it is. Also, after I do this, I can re-run my initial script and everything works perfectly fine.

I am using JupyterLab if that's relevant

[image: Image of the very first display(fig1) that isn't showing graph]

[image: Image of plt.show and display(fig1)]

I expect to see a graph, but I don't.